# OpenCV CascadeClassifier initialization

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I've installed opencv (2.3.1) and now I use it with Qt (SDK 1.1.3, Creator 2.3.0).
(I've used this tutorial: http://www.barbato.us/2011/12/20/opencv-2-3-qtcreator-windows/)

First thing i've tried was HelloWorld example (like the one in Getting Started on the official website), and there were no problems with it. I've also tried some other examples.

Now I've got a problem with example of face recognition. The code itself can be found here: http://www.opencv.org.cn/opencvdoc/2.3.1/html/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html, but when I try to run it, the program exits with code 0 as if everything was fine, but nothing actually happens. After some hours of trying to solve it I've found that the problem itself is in the CascadeClassifier variable. So if I have any working sample, and then I try to initialize an object of CascadeClassifier class, the program just exits with code 0 on this line.

```
CascadeClassifier face_cascade;
```

It also doesn't depend on this variable being global or not. I've also tried to initialize pointer, but the same thing happens on object creation.

---

Finally I've recompiled the whole library, and now everything is fine. 
Thanks for the answers!

Comment: does your code load `haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml` successfully?

Comment: How can I check it? My program fails just before loading, at the line I wrote in the original message

Comment: Try debugging! Or if you have no experience with debuggers, put some print statements before and after lines of interest.

Comment: That was the way I understood that the problem is in calling constructor of CascadeClassifier :)

Answer (score 0):

I would copy data from OCV to directory containing executable. The sample face detection data is in source tree of OpenCV `OpenCV-2.3.1/data/haarcascades/`. Copy `haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml` and `haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml` from there to target directory of your program.

Comment: I've already done it, but program closes at the constructor call of CascadeClassifier (no matter it is called with filename or not; the filename itself is correct, I've checked it)

Answer (score -1):

You can check if your classifier was loaded successfully with these code:

```
    if (!cascade.load(classifierdir)) {
    printf("Unable to load classifier from %s\n", classifierdir);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I can't try it, because if I do, the program will close at the line of initilization "cascade" variable, e.g.: `code` CascadeClassifier cascade; `code`